# Help with formula for calculated column in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a SharePoint choice column entitled month of year, I want to look at entries where the month selected is August, I want to then look at any holiday entries for the month of august which are numbered in a column entitled 'Holidays' and multiply this number by 3 to populate a new calculated column.

I am struggling to find what formula would provide this for me, any advice please?

Comment: Can you add screenshot of list view to get the idea about your data and also provide example of required calculation based on columns in your list & expected result in calculated column.

Comment: Sorry I can’t at the moment, but If this help I have a choice column which has the 12 months of the year and you can only select 1 month per entry, there is a further column to add the number of days holiday you wish to take for that month, I have a third column which I would like where the month of august is selected for it to multiply by 3 the number of holidays selected and auto-populate with the answer

Comment: Ok, got it for August month. What about other months?

Comment: Check my answer given below. Let me know if it works for you or if you need any further help on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Does this meet your needs?

```
=IF([Month]="August",[Holidays]*3,"")
```

Comment: Brilliant, that has worked. Thank you very much

Comment: If I wished to add a further month to this (July) and add July and august together and then multiply by 3, can you give any advice on the formula please?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your "Holidays" column is of type "Number", you can created a calculated column for your requirements and use below formula for calculated column:

```
=IF([Month] = "August", [Holidays] * 3, [Holidays])
```

This formula results in `[Holidays] * 3` if selected month is August else shows the existing `[Holidays]` value as is.

**Calculated column settings**:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))